# Form is not validating

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure what I'm doing wrong here (form submits / does not validate). I'm not an expert, so I'm hoping someone a little smarter than me will be able to quickly catch what I'm doing wrong:

```
<script>
    function validateForm(){

        var first = $('#first_name').val();
        if(first==null || first==''){
            if ($('span:contains("Enter a valid first name")').length==0){
                $(this).closest('div').addClass('has-error');
                $(this).after('<span class="error" style="color:red;font-size:14px;">Enter a valid first name</span>');
            }
            return false;
        }

        var last = $('#last_name').val();
        if(last==null || last==''){

            if ($('span:contains("Enter a valid last name")').length==0){
                $(this).closest('div').addClass('has-error');
                $(this).after('<span class="error" style="color:red;font-size:14px;">Enter a valid last name</span>');
            }
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }

    </script>
```

The html:

```
<form id="myid" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

....a form...

</form>
```

I'm using similar syntax to validate form inputs on `.focusout()`, and it works fine.

Comment: The function always returns false.

Comment: Looks like you're using jQuery, is there a reason why you're not using something like: `$('#myid').submit(function({}));` Also wondering, have you tried using `console.log()` to debug, because the function is most likely being called, just not doing what you are expecting it to do.

Comment: The function returns false when it sees a validation error, and then at the end it also returns false. Shouldn't the last one be `return true`?

Comment: @Barmar that may be to stop the default action of a form submission ?

Comment: @mkirkpatrick I think he wants the default submission when there are no validation errors.

Comment: Well, if that's not the case we need more information to help

Comment: Wrapping validation in """$('#myid').submit(function(){...the function...});""" AND changing the last return to """return true;""" solved the problem. I get the last return, but any reason the function alone initiated via onsumit="return validateForm()" wouldn't have worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the form to act normally if there are no errors, you should have the function return true:

```
 function validateForm(){

    var first = $('#first_name').val();
    if(first==null || first==''){
        if ($('span:contains("Enter a valid first name")').length==0){
            $(this).closest('div').addClass('has-error');
            $(this).after('<span class="error" style="color:red;font-size:14px;">Enter a valid first name</span>');
        }
        return false;
    }

    var last = $('#last_name').val();
    if(last==null || last==''){

        if ($('span:contains("Enter a valid last name")').length==0){
            $(this).closest('div').addClass('has-error');
            $(this).after('<span class="error" style="color:red;font-size:14px;">Enter a valid last name</span>');
        }
        return false;
    }

    return true; // everything went okay !
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The last

```
return false;
```

should be

```
return true;
```

You get there when there haven't been any validation errors. Returning `false` tells the browser not to submit the form, you need to return something else. You can also just remove the line entirely, since anything other than `false` allows the form to submit.